# Move up row using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Consider a QListWidget and two buttons "move up" and "move down". Clicking on move up, the current rows should move up one row, analogously for "move down". I want to change the sequence of selected items/rows, if the row position is first and again using move up then it should be going to last of selected indexes.

This code for move up:

```
currentRow = self.listWidget.selectedIndexes()
for item in currentRow:
    if item.row() != 0:
        currentItem = self.listWidget.takeItem(item.row())
        if item.row() - 1 == 0:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(item.row(), currentItem)
        else:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(item.row() - 1, currentItem)
        currentItem.setSelected(True)
```

If i selected the 3 rows and "move up" up to top and then after pressing again move up button the first row should come last and second was going up at top.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: You haven't provided enough information... please create an [mre]